# ANDROID STUDIO Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to `Android studio` and I have been facing this kind of error when I compile the android project that I bought from codecanyon. What am I missing"?

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
>   Could not determine artifacts for io.realm:realm-android-library-object-server:4.3.1: No cached version available for offline mode

Comment: did @GParekar's answer work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is why, because You have enabled using Gradle in offline mode, but there is no cache available there. I hope this will work for you.

Check If you are working in offline mode. If not then please un-check it from below path.

**`File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Gradle-> Uncheck Offline Work`**

Comment: it worked! but another problem occured sir. what could possibly go wrong? org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/gradle/plugin/com/onesignal/onesignal-gradle-plugin/0.10.2/onesignal-gradle-plugin-0.10.2-sources.jar'.

Comment: classpath "gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.10.1, 0.99.99]" can you added this line in your project gradle file?

Comment: i already have this in my build.gradle file "classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.10.2'" should i still do your suggestion?

Comment: Bro. thank you so much. it is now working. android studio suggested for an update to gradle and then boom.

Answer (score 3):

Now offline mode option is moved to Gradle drawer in the top right corner, you can enable disable from here
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.project level build.gradle
2.click on -open for editing  in android studio
3.update gradle to latest
4.it will fix this issue``